# Click to Search

Tags: script, topbar

## About

This simple userscript adds a clickable search button to the Stack Exchange top bar, as the only current way to search is to press <kbd>enter</kbd>, which can be confusing for some.

You can select one of two forms for the button.

1. A link in the top bar (like "review," "help," etc.):

   [image: Link]
2. A button (like "Post Your Answer"):

   [image: Button]

You will be prompted to choose one each time you visit a new Stack Exchange site: your preference is stored with HTML5 `localStorage`. If your browser doesn't support this, the default is the link format shown above.

You can reset your preference for a particular site at any time by clicking the "reset" link in the footer:

[image: Reset]

It was inspired by [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269395/we-should-be-able-to-initiate-a-search-using-the-mouse) on [Meta Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com/).

## Download

You can download the script from [Greasy Fork](https://greasyfork.org/scripts/4401-click-to-search) ([Direct Link](https://greasyfork.org/scripts/4401-click-to-search/code/Click%20to%20Search.user.js)) or [view the source code](https://greasyfork.org/scripts/4401-click-to-search/code).

## Installation

See the [script](/questions/tagged/script) tag wiki for details on userscript installation.

## History

See the [Greasy Fork changelog](https://greasyfork.org/scripts/4401-click-to-search/versions).

## Contact

Please post bug reports or feature requests on this page as an answer or comment.